# Rails - Find all by course id where user = unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following table:

```
Tweet(id: integer, from_user: string, tweet_text: string, tweet_id: integer, course_id: integer, tweet_already_exists: boolean, tweet_posted_to_reviews: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

And, for a specific course, I'd like to get the last 50 tweets, unique by user. I've gotten this far:

```
 Tweet.order("tweet_id desc").find_all_by_course_id(@course.id).first(50)
```

The problem with this is that if a user has tweeted more than once, they appear twice (both tweets appear) and I'd only like to get that person's latest tweet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit complex, but I'm not sure it's possible to do the query you want to do in a simpler way:

```rb
Tweet.where("tweets.updated_at >= (SELECT MAX(t.updated_at) FROM tweets AS t WHERE t.from_user=tweets.from_user)").order("tweets.tweet_id desc").find_all_by_course_id(@course.id).first(50)
```

Comment: Hi tsherif, this is brilliant! It works almost perfectly! The only thing is that it is pulling the user's first tweet (instead of the last one). When I change `.order("tweets.tweet_id desc")` to `.order("tweets.tweet_id asc")` it only changes the ordering of the tweets on the page (v.s. pulling the user's latest tweet). any idea on how to fix that? also, do you happen to know if this query will work on PG (site is on heroku using Cedar stack)? Thanks again for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: Try changing the `>=` to `<=` and the `MAX` in the nested query to `MIN`. Not sure about the PG stuff though...

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much tsherif, it works locally. Please let me know if there are any specific resources you recommend I look at to understand how you built the query. Thanks again!!

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped :) I think if you look up nested queries in Google, you should find some info on how these kinds of queries are build. Good luck!

Comment: BTW, you could also try by `MAX(tweets.created_at)`. It sort of depends how your table is organized.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but try this :

```
Tweet.find(:all, :select => 'DISTINCT from_user', :order => 'tweet_id desc')
```

Will give you the list of tweets without duplicated users. Query the result to get the courses.

---

You night also want to use the ruby method `uniq` which return an array without duplicate.

Comment: I've tried that but can't seem to make it work inside with all other parameters. Where would you add the uniq call (to find unique "from_user")?

Comment: You only have one table for everytthing (users, courses, tweets)?

Comment: In this case I have the Tweet table (with the fields outlined above - including the from_user) and a Course table, which has course_id, and other fields related to the courses. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks for your help Justin. This is giving me an array, not sure if there is a way to do this directly on active record. Basically, is there a way to add "find_all_by_course_id" to the query you posted?

Comment: Try adding `.find_all_by_course_id(your code)` after the query I gave you. Not sure if it is going to work, but it is worth a try.

Comment: I think we're almost there. The following query works: `@tweets = Tweet.find(:all, :order => 'tweet_id desc', :conditions => {:course_id => @course.id})` but when I do this `@tweets = Tweet.find(:all, :select => 'DISTINCT from_user', :order => 'tweet_id desc', :conditions => {:course_id => @course.id})` I get the following error: ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError in Courses#show, missing attribute tweet_text